# Как завершить Task.Run?

Tags: c#, task

Делаю WebApi.
Команда Execute записывает запускает какое либо действие в цикле.
Команда StopTaskById отменяет эту задачу.

Перепробовал множество вариантов из интернета. Задача либо не отменяется, либо пробрасывается ошибка, либо задача не останавливается.

Что делаю не так?

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebServer.Database;
using WebServer.Enums;
using WebServer.Extensions;
using WebServer.Models.ServiceParameters;
using WebServer.Utils;

namespace WebServer.Services;

[ApiController]
[Tags("[SERVICE]")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MnemonicCheckerService : AppResponse
{
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Execute([FromBody] MnemonicCheckerParams mnemonicCheckerParams)
    {
        try
        {
            //Создаем токен отмены
            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            
            //Создаем задачу
            _tasker = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                //Задача выполняет какое то действие в цикле
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        Debug.WriteLine("AFTER" + new Random().Next(1000));
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    //Если какая то ошибка записываем
                }
            }, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            
            //Отправляет на клиента сообщение, что задача успешно запущена
            return Json(true,$"The task has been successfully created! ID: {_task.Id} GUID: {_task.TaskGuidId}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(false, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]/{id}")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> StopTaskById(int id)
    {     
        //Останавливаем задачу и уведомляем пользователя, что задача успешно остановлена  
        try
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel(false);
            return Json(true,
                $"Task successfully interrupted ID: {_task.Id} GUID: {_task.TaskGuidId} SERVICE: {_task.Service}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            return Json(false, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я на вашем месте создал бы отдельный синглтон сервис, который зарегистрировал бы в контейнере, в нем сделал бы методы запуска и остановки, а в контроллере уже дергал бы их. Ну а так, `_tasker` статичен?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, _tasker статичный

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1000, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);`

Answer (score 1):

Добавь проверку состояния токена в цикл `while`

```
while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Debug.WriteLine("AFTER" + new Random().Next(1000));
}
```

Добавь обработку исключения `OperationCanceledException`

```
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // Задача была отменена
}
```

Если ваша задача завершилась нормально, то не надо вызывать `Dispose`, он вызовется автоматом при завершении задачи и объект сам разрушится.

Кроме это можно взять класс `System.Threading.Timer` вместо задачи

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class TimerExample
{
    private static Timer _timer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 1000);
        // Пауза на 10 секунд, чтобы таймер успел выполниться несколько раз
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        // Останавливаем таймер
        _timer.Dispose();
    }

    private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
    {
        // Код, который должен выполняться в цикле
        Console.WriteLine("TimerCallback: " + DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Либо через `Task.Wait()` или `Task.WaitAll()` вместо цикла `while(true)`

```
_task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        // do some work
        Task.Delay(1000, _cancellationToken).Wait();
        Debug.WriteLine("AFTER" + new Random().Next(1000));
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // task was canceled
        }
    }
}, _cancellationToken);
```

Через `StopTaskById`:

```
_cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
try
{
    _task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerExceptions[0] is TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // task was canceled
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас тоже непонятно зачем вручную `Dispose` вызывать, может всё-таки лучше `using` использовать?

Comment: Согласен, using  будет лучшим решением. пример кода 'code using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource()) { //... }' лучше использовать нестатическую переменную и создавать её внутри Execute, а не в классе.

Comment: @versetty777 ответ можно редактировать